# datetime: Handling data types

Tags: python, datetime

I have a set of shop products in my database, each with their unique time_added key in MongoDB, however, I run into a problem when parsing it.

I use two methods in my code to set the `time_added` variable to the db:

> ```
> import time
>
> ts = time.time()
> ```

**Type A:** Produces a unix timestamp, example:

```
1646771033.712499
```

and

> ```
> from datetime import datetime
>  
> now = datetime.now()
> ```

**Type B:** Produces a datetime.datetime object in Mongo, example:

```
2022-03-10T19:13:26.964+00:00
```

However, I'd like to parse both types in my code, I tried:

```
today = datetime.now()
before = datetime.fromtimestamp(time_added)

today_validated = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
before_validated = before.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

today_date = s.datetime.strptime(today_validated, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
before_date = s.datetime.strptime(before_validated, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
delta = (today_date - before_date).days

print(delta)
```

However, I get an error:

```
2022-03-10 19:13:26.964000 is not a valid timestamp. int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

I understand the error here, I just can't get my head around converting this as some may contain Type A and some Type B

Comment: You could do some clunky conditional parsing, but the bigger problem is that you are using two different date/time formats to store data. That's something that should certainly be consistent within a given property, and probably globally consistent throughout your code base

Comment: Totally agree with @NickBailey but to answer your specific question, if the data coming from the database can be converted to float then you could assume that it's a Unix-style timestamp. Otherwise use strptime to decipher it

Comment: @NickBailey, Yep, This is what we're currently doing, but the amount of products is large and we can't change it without updating, reading each item (cost problems), I'd like to parse this old type (as it's removed on newly added products)

Comment: `time.time()` gives you Unix time while `datetime.now()` gives you a naive datetime object (local time). Be careful when converting between the two - better set a time zone (e.g. `datetime.timezone.utc`) to avoid ambiguities.